# Passing Data to a Layout Page

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have a `layout` page that has variables that need to be filled.  Example:

```
@ModelType KarateAqua.schoolModel

<html>
    <body>

        @RenderBody()

        <div id="footer">
            <div class="content">
                <div class="bottom_logo">
                    <a href="/"><span class="inv">@Model.schoolName</span></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I don't want to populate this in every `ActionResult`.  Is there a way to pass data to a `layout` page once and do it for all instances?

Comment: The best answer is: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13225315/pass-data-to-layout-that-are-common-to-all-pages

Answer (score 9, accepted):

OK since you want this to be set once you can make use of a partial view. However depending on your needs you will need to have several partial views (may be not ideal if sections are going to be scattered across the _layout page)

your partial view will look like

```
@model KarateAqua.schoolModel

<div class="bottom_logo">
<a href="/"><span class="inv">@Model.schoolName</span>
</div>
```

Controller

```
public class SchoolController : Controller
{
     public ActionResult Index()
     {
          //get schoolModel  
          return PartialView(schoolModel);
     }
}
```

in your _layout.cshtml place this line where you want to have the partial view to be inserted

```
@Html.Action("Index","School")
```

Answer (score 16):

Create an action filter and decorate your controller classes. Inside the action filter you have access to put values in the viewbag which are available to your layout.

This will run on each request and you will not have to set the values in each action. You can look for and ignore things like a child request and ajax requests which typically do not use the layout anyways and not set your viewbag values for those.

Below is a sample of an attribute i created to copy an object from the session and make it available to the layout via the ViewBag

```
public class CurrentUserAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        // Don't bother running this for child action or ajax requests
        if (!filterContext.IsChildAction && !filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest())
        {

            if (filterContext.HttpContext.Session != null)
            {
                var currentUser = filterContext.HttpContext.Session["CurrentUser"] as CurrentUser;
                if (currentUser != null)
                {
                    filterContext.Controller.ViewBag.CurrentUser = currentUser;
                }
            }
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: This isn't perfectly clean (not strongly typed, etc.), but it's the cleanest I've found. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

You can open a code block on the layout page and fill the object there.  This will execute every time the layout page is being used.  The benefit is that you do not have to alter anything on your controller:

```
@{
    KarateAqua.schoolModel data = YourBusinessLayer.Method();
}

<html>
<body>

    @RenderBody()

    <div id="footer">
        <div class="content">
            <div class="bottom_logo">
                <a href="/"><span class="inv">@data.schoolName</span></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Code blocks in views should only be used when no other option is available imo. You would make the view too smart. Its a view and it should present data based on a modal thats good enough to work without code blocks.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `ViewBag` or `ViewData` to pass data to your Layout pages.

**Layout**

```
<html>
<body>
@RenderBody()

<div id="footer">
<div class="content">
<div class="bottom_logo">
<a href="/"><span class="inv">@ViewBag.schoolName</span>
</div></div></div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult Index(){
   ViewBag.schoolName = "Bayside Tigers";
   return View();
}
```

Comment: But would I have to do that for each controller action?

Comment: Yes, just like you would have to return a model for each action.

Comment: Poor software design.

Comment: @CMate - Poor comment

Comment: @Gabe, please a learn a little about reusability, which is a key aspect when creating a software with sustainable maintainability. It shows a very poor software design, when a code segment must be repeated at the end of every action method, making it redundant and hard to maintain. It is especially bad, when the ASP.NET MVC framework offers base classes to avoid such a bad programming scheme. For more information on the topic, see the ActionFilterAttribute class on MSDN. It was also presented in JBeckton's answer.

Comment: What if you want to get a result from the database?  For example,  ViewBag.htmlraw = db.Entries.Find(3);  then how would you call it in the view?    <div>
            @ViewBag.htmlraw
        </div>

Comment: The previous comment can't be edited, but this is how I did it:           var result = new HelpEntry();
            result = db.HelpEntries.Find(id);
            ViewBag.htmlraw = result.Description;

Comment: He doesn't want to populate this in every ActionResult.  downvote.

Answer (score 1):

You could always create action that returns a partial view of your header.

Just add this to your `layout` page:

```
<html>
    <head> 
    </head>
        <body>
            @{ Html.RenderAction("header", "MyController", new { area = "" }); }

            @RenderBody()
//...
```

Answer (score 1):

**Your Layout Page:**

```
@ViewBag.LayoutVar
```

**Your HomeController:**

```
public class HomeController : BaseController
{
   //Here some logic...
}
```

**Your BaseController**

```
namespace ProjectName.Controllers
{
    public class BaseController : Controller
    {

        public YetkiController()
        {
            //This parameter is accessible from layout
            ViewBag.LayoutVar = "Suat";
        }
    }
}
```

Logic is easy: You create BaseController which includes every global parameters you will use in layout. *(Like username or other data based parameters)*

You inherit (call) `BaseController` to get all parameters into your current controller.

Answer (score 1):

I used `HTTP Session` to persist the data between different pages -

```
//Opening page controller
public ActionResult Index()
{    
    Session["something"]="xxxx";
    return View();
}
```

In the shared `_layout` page;

```
//persistent data   
<p>Hello, @Session["something"]!</p>
```

Hope this helps but it won't work if you start from a different page from the default one that has been set.