# 'System.Web.WebPages.Html.HtmlHelper' does not contain a defintion for 'Action'

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

Thanks for reading this.

In the _Layout.cshtml page I use the @RenderPage to call the header:

```
@RenderPage("/Shared/_header.cshtml")
```

It has this:

```
<div id="Header"> Home </div>
```

Want to make it clickable to the default action ("Index")

When I tried this:

```
<div id="Header"> @Html.Action("Index", "MyController") </div>
```

The 'Action' is underlined in red with this error:

```
'System.Web.WebPages.Html.HtmlHelper' does not contain a defintion for 'Action' and no extension ......
```

"System.Web.Mvc" is referenced in the project as well in the config file:

```
<add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to copy `Views/Web.config` to `/Shared`.

[This will tell Razor to use the MVC base type & parser](http://blog.slaks.net/2011/02/dissecting-razor-part-3-razor-and-mvc.html)

Comment: Thanks; I know I can move the _header and footer to /view/shared

it's that ok?
BTW, thanks for your blog.

Comment: Yes; that would be better.  Typically, though, you should put the header directly in the layout, not in a separate file.

Comment: Also, call `Html.Partial` (MVC version), not `RenderPage()` (WebPages version)

Comment: You mean something like this: 
[link] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10552502/passing-data-to-a-layout-page)

Comment: If you need to pass data, call the child action directly from the layout.

Answer (score 0):

I've moved from mvc4 to mvc5
All I needed to do is change this key value at web.config 
from 2

```
 <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
```