# How to pass data to _Layout.cshtml

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

At _Layout.cshtml used by all pages, when any background image is selected, I want to display the selected picture. But, I dont ,unfortunately, know how to pass this data to _Layout.cshtml.

AT _Layout.cshtml

```
<style type="text/css">
        #body-bg {
            background-image: url('//I want to change here');
        }
</style>
```

How should i do? From any controller, this data should be pass to _Layout.cshtml but how?

Comment: You can using a base view model containing the property, or pass it using `ViewBag` or `ViewData`

Comment: Depending on how your handling it, you could use a template with a default value there as well. (ie. `@RenderSection(...)`)

Answer (score 2):

The most robust way is using a base viewmodel class and put a string property to hold image path:

**Model Class**

```
public class BaseViewModel
{
    public string BackgroundImage { get; set; }
}
```

**_Layout.cshtml**

```
@model BaseViewModel
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
     <!-- other styles, meta tags, etc. -->
     <style type="text/css">
     #body-bg {
         background-image: url('@Model.BackgroundImage');
     }
</head>
<body>
     <!-- body part -->
     @RenderBody()
</body>
</html>
```

If you're using relative path (e.g. `~/Images/Selected.png`) instead of absolute path to refer image paths, use `UrlHelper.Content` with string property as argument:

```
#body-bg {
     background-image: url('@Url.Content(Model.BackgroundImage)');
}
```

Also don't forget to set viewmodel's string property inside controller action method:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    // other stuff
    return View(new BaseViewModel { BackgroundImage = "/path/to/image.png" });
}
```

NB: You can use `ViewBag` or `ViewData` besides a viewmodel (they're both automatically passed to view), by changing `Model` to `ViewBag`/`ViewData`:

```
// View (CSS)
#body-bg {
    background-image: url('@ViewBag.BackgroundImage');
}

// Controller
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    // other stuff
    ViewBag.BackgroundImage = "/path/to/image.png";
    return View();
}
```

Note that `ViewBag` is dynamic, possibly extra check required to prevent `NullReferenceException` thrown when using `ViewBag` property.

References:

[Passing Data to Views (MS Documentation)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/overview#passing-data-to-views)

[Pass data to layout that are common to all pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13225315/pass-data-to-layout-that-are-common-to-all-pages)

[Passing Data to a Layout Page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10552502/passing-data-to-a-layout-page)